# Powershell - SQL Database show users permission

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

I'm writing, because I've been stuck. I'm new in SQL+ Powershell. I have SQL Server with 10 DBs.
I need to check

1. check if user's accounts exists in SQL (Get-SQLLogin - that's clear)
2. check what kind of permissions the user has on each database
3. after AD.2 prints on screen a list of permissions for each database

I've stuck here:

```
foreach($item in $dt){
    $server = $item.server
    $user = "domain\$($item.user)"
    $database = $item.db

     Get-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $server -LoginName $user 
     }
```

Thank you so much in advance!
Cheers

Comment: So what have you written so far? Why isn't what you've written no working?

Comment: I have a list of servers, databases and users. I can filter existing users, but here I've been stuck on AD2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaUserPermission will do what you need.

There are a few other cmdlets for permissions at https://dbatools.io/commands/#Security